# What's a good, cheap registrar that supports IPv6 glue?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, domain-registrar

I'm currently using namecheap, but I'd like to start adding ipv6 glue entries to my nameserver records, and they don't seem to support ipv6 glue reliably. What's a good, cheap registrar that supports ipv6 glue for the major TLDs (particularly .info, .net, .org, and .us)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GoDaddy support .com and .net, not sure about the others.

gkg.net also support glue records apparently, although not used them.

There's a nice list for all others [here](http://www.sixxs.net/faq/dns/?faq=ipv6glue).

Answer (score 1):

According to the link posted by Adam, the `.us` zone doesn't support IPv6 glue at all.

Answer (score 1):

We use opensrs.net for our domains and our customer domains. They will manually add IPv6 glue if you ask and they are currently working on rolling out new backend code to support this in their reseller/end user system.

Answer (score 1):

Joker.com is my recommendation (I use them) - left GoDaddy after they redirected one of my domains to a "for sale" site for a week.  GoDaddy is bad news, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

[Name.com](http://name.com/) also just recently started [supporting IPv6 glue](http://blog.name.com/2010/07/full-ipv6-support-here-at-name-com/#disqus_thread) (for all TLDs?). (since July 2010)

Answer (score 0):

loopia.se are free and supports IPv6 glue

Answer (score 0):

[Gandi.net](http://gandi.net/) has served me very well, and supports IPv6 glue.

Comment: Are you sure? I haven't tried personally yet, but their wiki says otherwise: http://wiki.gandi.net/en/domains/faq/technical-parameters?s=ipv6#can-i-configure-my-domain-with-my-own-dns

Comment: You were right, but according to their newest release they do support IPv6 glue records now. See http://www.gandibar.net/post/2010/11/23/Gandi-has-upgraded-to-V307

Answer (score 0):

BareMetal can support IPv6 GLUE for .ca.  You may have to contact support to get it done still, though.